# AWS RDS MYSQL How do I reduce the DB size?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reduce the database size on AWS RDS MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24491/how-do-i-reduce-the-database-size-on-aws-rds-mysql)

I have a mysql DB on Amazon. It is bigger than I need and I don't want to pay so much.

How do I make it smaller? Their site says you have to do it some magic way (from backups or such), but I don't want to mistakenly wack it!

[image: RDS DB instance storage]

Comment: Can I assume you have tried an Optimize table?

Comment: Do you have this set up as a multi-AZ database?

Comment: By the way AWS RDS will NOT EVER Let you reduce DB Size on RDS.

Answer (score 4):

One idea (wholly un-researched, so there might be a better way, but this should work):

1. Create a new RDS instance that is smaller in size.
2. Dump the old one into the new one:

   ```
   mysqldump -h <old-RDS> -u <user> -p<password> | mysql -h <new-RDS> -u <user> -p<password>
   ```
3. Whack the old one.

Of course, this assumes your total db size is smaller than 20GB, and that you're just looking to end up with a smaller instance. If you're trying to shrink the size of the database, in total, that's a different question.

Comment: Amazon has snapshots. I was hoping snapshots somehow could be used. Your method requires a complete download/upload which will cost (I/O Rate $0.10 per 1 million requests).

Comment: @aaaaaaa Well, yes. It does. But you're talking < 20GB right? That's about $2: http://aws.amazon.com/rds/. Look at the data in / out pricing. Also, how many millions of objects do you have in your db? I can't imagine this would cost more than a lunch at an upscale fast-food restaurant.

Comment: Of course if you have an EC2 instance in the same AZ as the two RDS instances, you can run this from there and save on transfer costs.

Comment: @Christopher +1 - concise way of my answer, I would select this as my anser.

Comment: This is an awesome solution. I fleshed it out a little more: `mysqldump -h old-db-host -u old-db-user -pold-db-pass old-db-name | mysql -h new-db-host -u new-db-user -pnew-db-pass new-db-name`

Comment: In my case, the migration didn't work without @T.BrianJones's enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your instance to a minimum of 5 GB of storage.

Here is the [related documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.MySQL.html).

Comment: "you cannot reduce the amount of storage allocated." - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.MySQL.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP AWS SDK (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/

See the RDS Section:

Something along these lines might work (extracted from example, slightly modified).

```
    $rds = new AmazonRDS();

$response = $rds->create_db_instance('myInstance', 5, 'db.m1.small', 'MySQL', 'dbUser', 'dbPassword', array(
    'DBName' => 'myDatabase',
    'DBSecurityGroups' => 'default',
    'PreferredMaintenanceWindow' => 'Sun:05:00-Sun:09:00',
    'BackupRetentionPeriod' => 1,
    'PreferredBackupWindow' => '03:00-05:00',
    'MultiAZ' => true,
    'AutoMinorVersionUpgrade' => true
));

// Success?
var_dump($response->isOK())
```

So that will create your new db, then simply follow the migration guide after downsizing your orginal DB at http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2933